# Looking for example of a Random Forest tutorial to estimate spatial distribution

Tags: spatial-statistics, classification, references, land-classification, random-forest

Could anyone point me to a Random Forest tutorial for predicting a spatial random variable? Or an easy dataset to try to work through.

For Decision Trees and Random Forests, I found some very good tutorials from Trevor Stephens, Kaggle, and Datacamp, [here](http://trevorstephens.com/post/73770963794/titanic-getting-started-with-r-part-5-random), [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic), and [here](https://www.datacamp.com/courses/kaggle-tutorial-on-machine-learing-the-sinking-of-the-titanic). But I'd like to look at a spatial example - I've come across a lot of literature on this subject but nothing as clear cut as the above links. The closest thing perhaps would be Jeffrey Evan's code [here](http://evansmurphy.wix.com/evansspatial#!random-forest-sdm/c1iuu), but it appears to be unfinished.

Comment: Have you seen this example from @JeffreyEvans: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/39021/8104?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using R and a hyperspectral AVIRIS image of the Kennedy Space Centre which is provided for testing spatial classifications.

```r
## required packages for spatial data random forest analysis
require(raster) 
require(rgdal)
install.packages("randomForest")
require(randomForest)

## download the aviris data
download.file("http://www.csr.utexas.edu/hyperspectral/data/KSC/KSC_data.bin", "KSC_data.bin")
download.file("http://www.csr.utexas.edu/hyperspectral/data/KSC/KSC_data.bin.hdr", "KSC_data.bin.hdr")

## download the ground truth data
download.file("http://www.csr.utexas.edu/hyperspectral/data/KSC/KSC_classes.bin", "KSC_classes.bin")
download.file("http://www.csr.utexas.edu/hyperspectral/data/KSC/KSC_classes.bin.hdr", "KSC_classes.bin.hdr")

bild <- stack("KSC_data.bin") #create raster stack

## plot to see what you are working with
plotRGB(bild, 25, 15, 5, stretch="lin") #true color composite
plotRGB(bild, 40, 25, 15, stretch="lin") #NIR/R/G-false color composite

classes <- stack("KSC_classes.bin") #import the ground truth data
gt <- rasterToPolygons(classes)

gt.class <- as.factor(t(gt@data)) #read class labels

gt.ref <- extract(bild, gt) #read reflectance values from image

## Random Forest classification
rfmod <- randomForest(gt.ref, gt.class) #create rf model

map <- predict(bild, rfmod) #predict classes with rf model

cl <- colorRampPalette(colors()[c (81, 152, 142, 493, 24, 652, 620, 254, 102, 624, 417, 498, 26)]) #one color per class

plot(map, col=cl(13), legend=F) #plot the result of the classification

writeRaster(map, "KSC_RandomForest.tif", format="GTiff") #export of the classified image
```

Source: This example is adapted from a lecture by Hannes Feilhauer and can also be found in the [FAU GISwiki (in German)](http://gis.wiki.fau.de/mediawiki/index.php/Random_Forest).