# Random Forest out of the bag and confusion matrix

Tags: r, remote-sensing, classification, random-forest, confusion-matrix

I have implemented Random Forest classifier to classify remote sensing data in R. The original code comes from here:

[How to perform Random Forest land classification?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39021/how-to-perform-random-forest-land-classification)

Everything works fine, but what I need is to obtain confusion matrix and out of the bag error for fast classification accuracy assessment. I have created junk dataset for validating functionality of the whole script itself (only 2 classes). I added parallel computing to speed up computations.

I am wondering if my implementation is correct and If I will be able to obtain confusion matrix and out of the bag error when I will add much more features describing classes later. Here is part of my code:

```
sdata <- readOGR(dsn = vyber_shp, layer = "trenink")

# extraction from raster to be classified

rdata <- data.frame(extract(r, sdata))

# create random forest model in parallel

cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())

registerDoParallel(cl)

rf.mdl <- foreach(ntree=rep(125, 4), .combine = combine, .packages = 'randomForest') 
%dopar% {randomForest(x=rdata, y=sdata$Class, ntree=500, 
proximity=TRUE, importance=TRUE, confusion=TRUE, 
do.trace=TRUE, err.rate=TRUE) 
    }

stopCluster(cl)

# classify raster in parallel

beginCluster()

predikce <- clusterR(r, raster::predict, args=list(model=rf.mdl))

endCluster()

# write and save result of classification as raster image

klasifikace <- writeRaster(predikce, filename='Klasifikace_RandomForest', 
format='HFA', options='INTERLEAVE=BSQ', datatype='INT2S', overwrite=TRUE)

varImpPlot(rf.mdl)

rf.mdl$confusion
```

Comment: I am not clear on what you are asking here. Are you not getting a confusion matrix returned with the randomForests object created from doParallel? The error OOB distributions will be a matrix in "err.rate", where each column represents the global and then each classes error and a confusion matrix will be in "confusion". Please clarify what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

The `combine` function (which is used in `foreach`) does not store the relevant components into the final `randomForest` object. See `?randomForest::combine`:

> The `confusion`, `err.rate`, `mse` and `rsq` components (as well
>   as the corresponding components in the `test` component, if exist)
>   of the combined object will be `NULL`.

But the `predict` method returns OOB predictions if the `newdata` argument is omitted:

```
library("doSNOW")
library("foreach")

cl <- makeCluster(2, type="SOCK")
registerDoSNOW(cl)

set.seed(1)
x <- subset(iris, select=-Species)
y <- iris$Species

rf <- foreach(ntree=rep(250, 4), .combine=combine, .packages="randomForest") %dopar%
      randomForest(x=x, y=y, ntree=ntree, norm.votes=FALSE)

rf
# Call:
#  randomForest(x = x, y = y, ntree = ntree, norm.votes = FALSE) 
#                Type of random forest: classification
#                      Number of trees: 1000
# No. of variables tried at each split: 2

# `predict.randomForest` returns OOB predictions if `newdata` is not given
rf_pred <- predict(rf)

caret::confusionMatrix(rf_pred, y)
# Confusion Matrix and Statistics
#
#             Reference
# Prediction   setosa versicolor virginica
#   setosa         50          0         0
#   versicolor      0         47         3
#   virginica       0          3        47
#
# Overall Statistics
#
#                Accuracy : 0.96
#                  95% CI : (0.915, 0.985)
#     No Information Rate : 0.333
#     P-Value [Acc > NIR] : <2e-16
#
#                   Kappa : 0.94
#  Mcnemar's Test P-Value : NA
#
# Statistics by Class:
#
#                      Class: setosa Class: versicolor Class: virginica
# Sensitivity                  1.000             0.940            0.940
# Specificity                  1.000             0.970            0.970
# Pos Pred Value               1.000             0.940            0.940
# Neg Pred Value               1.000             0.970            0.970
# Prevalence                   0.333             0.333            0.333
# Detection Rate               0.333             0.313            0.313
# Detection Prevalence         0.333             0.333            0.333
# Balanced Accuracy            1.000             0.955            0.955
```

See also:

- [Combining randomForests in R, why are the err.rate, mse and rsq components NULL](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14045/combining-randomforests-in-r-why-are-the-err-rate-mse-and-rsq-components-null)
- [Why do I need bag composition to calculate OOB error of combined random forest model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35609)