# How to Classify With Multiple Ancillary Datasets using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, classification, otb-applications

I've tried using the classifiers in ArcMap which only supports one ancillary dataset and I tried using Orfeo in QGIS 2.18, though the Orfeo Image Classification tool does not accept any ancillary raster datasets. I can create a training model using multiple bands and images in Orfeo but Image Classification only accepts one raster file so I can't feed it the extra ancillary data I used during the training.

Besides the original satellite image, I want to add in NDVI, NDWI, and DEM's to help the classifier just so you guys have an idea of what I'm trying to do. I haven't come across something like this besides creating a completely custom classifier.

How do I Classify With Multiple Ancillary Datasets using QGIS?

EDIT: I've figured it out. I just make a new composite raster image which includes the ancillary data as additional bands or create a virtual raster catalog. This way I can use the new composite raster with classifiers in any Remote Sensing software which often accepts only 1 raster file at a time. I've already tested this with my low spectral resolution data and it helped my classification output by adding NDVI and a NDWI as extra bands.

Comment: Maximum Liklihood in ArcGIS allows for the use of multiple bands: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/maximum-likelihood-classification.htm. Also, I would recommend performing the classification using R, which allows you tremendous freedom in setting up your parameters. Here is something to get you started: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/39021/8104.

Comment: I reduced the scope of this question by retrofitting to its first answer. If you also wish to ask how to do it using ArcGIS Desktop then please do that in a separate question.

Comment: I just realized, is it a sensible thing to include supplementary data as additional bands in Remote Sensing Data then do that in MLC? @Aaron

For example I have a 4 band image then I just create a new composite image with NDVI and Radar as band 5 and 6 respectively?

Comment: @pbroto You should be able to include the individual bands including NDVI and radar without creating composite bands.

Comment: Ah I see now, thanks for the tip. Though from what I can tell this is only available for the MLC classifier in ArcMap? The other methods such as Random Forest/SVM or classifiers in other software might have to use a composite image of bands and ancillary data by the looks of it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am misunderstanding your needs, I can recommend the use of [Semi Automatic Classification plugin](https://fromgistors.blogspot.com/p/semi-automatic-classification-plugin.html) in QGIS, which is actively developed and very well documented, and in which a **complete dataset composed of any amount of bands of any number of files** works as input for the classification.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this plugin, it's my first time using it and the classification process is interesting. What I wanted to do is combine RGB+NIR bands for bands 1-4. I'm trying to experiment adding ancillary data to the classification methodology by adding it as a raster band. For example, NDVI values for band 5 and Radar for band 6.

Comment: @pbroto, the result of a classification is a shapefile with the polygons resulting from the classification. The origin is a dataset of bands of one or more files, it is not necessary that all data be in a single file. Maybe what you're trying to do is [create a virtual raster catalog](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/training_manual/rasters/data_manipulation.html?highlight=virtual%20raster#basic-fa-create-a-virtual-raster) before?